# How to create dynamic names from an array for a form in Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I need to send a form dynamic but I don't know how create the names for the Form.

This is my code:

Ts

```
export class MiPage implements OnInit {

  public inputs = [];
  FormData: any;
  DataForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  payLoad: any;

 constructor() { }

generateFormControls(formData: any)
    {
        let tempGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
        formData.forEach(i=>{

            console.info(i.name);
            tempGroup.addControl(i.name, new FormControl(''))
        })
        return tempGroup;
    }

    PreviewData() 
    {
         this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.DataForm.value);
    }

    data() {
      
       for (let numero of resp.datos){

        this.inputs[numero.id_producto]=numero.id_producto;  //the array
             
      }
     
     //So I manually create the names, but this is dynamic because it is generated from a query in the database

  this.FormData = [
      {
      name:'429'
    },{
      name:'428'
    }]

//But I need to create it dynamically. For example, but it gives me syntax error un "For"

this.FormData = [
      
      for(let datos of this.inputs) {

        name: datos

      }  
    
    ]


  }
}
```

Thank you very much, I hope you can help me. And know if this if it's possible to do it like this or how I can dynamically create the names

Comment: OScar, you can use FormArray -instead formGroup-: FormArray=new FormArray(this.formData.map(x=>new FormControl(x))-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might `push` the elements into the array.

```
this.FormData = [];
  
for(let datos of this.inputs) {

    this.FormData.push({name: datos});

}
```

or in a more concise way using `map`, as suggested by @Eliseo in the comment bellow:

```
this.FormData = this.inputs.map(x => ({name:x}));
```

Comment: use "map" (it's more "elegant"): `this.FormData=this.inputs.map(x=>({name:x}))`